# Starting a tls communication with python asyncio

Tags: python, ssl

I have some python code snippet that uses `asyncio` and initiates a "plain" connection:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_connection(lambda: MyCustomClassProtocol(loop), sock=client_socket)
loop.run_until_complete(coro)
```

The point is my plain connection switches to a tls one once some exchanges have happened. In the traditional way one would do this:

```
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(client_socket, do_handshake_on_connect=False)
ssl_sock.do_handshake()
```

But I don't really know how I can handle this with `asyncio`. My `data_received` method receives the ciphered content though, so I guess I can do something to decipher it, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Kamyar is correct: there's no official way to do it in 3.4. There's a [ticket open](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/79) that might get fixed in 3.6. Until then, I have a super-hacky, void-the-warranty workaround: `self._transport = self._loop._make_ssl_transport(self._transport._sock, self, ssl_context, server_side=True)`. This assumes that your protocol saves a reference to the transport in `self._transport` and a reference to the event loop in `self._loop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, up to python 3.5 there is not standard way to do  it! As of python 3.5, there is a new thing called MemoryBIO within ssl module with which you can wrap your socket for TLS.
You have a couple of options here:

1. Use Python  traditional (sync) socket and loop.executor for wrapping it in an async coroutine.
2. Using SSL instead of TLS. Most of servers allow it,but there are still exceptions (like Apple's APNs!)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that use only public API of asyncio:

Make a copy of create_connection and modify it to have it return socket object (just a few lines), and use low level functions to operate it (such as sock_connect, sock_read). When you need to startSSL, just pass the sock to open_connection